# How to use login and password from url to get request

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend

I open my site with the address "http://login:password@localhost:3000/"
How can I put an authorization data from url to get the requests? Like this:

```
Request URL: http://root:root@localhost:3000/vendor.chunk.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

How can I get username and password from url with a Javascript? It is necessary for setting the authorization header for get request.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` function to achieve that, but it is highly unsafe to put your password into a URL. Whoever sees the URL, including the ISP can easily hack it.

```js
var url = "http://login:password@localhost:3000/"
let parts = url.split("//")[1].split("@")[0].split(":");
let username = parts[0];
let password = parts[1];
console.log(username, password);
```

Comment: how can i get this url in js code? this information input in Search line and not available in  javascript global scope

Comment: @pashamih just use `window.location.href` instead of `url` in the code above. I have used a hard-coded variable for the purpose of testability, but you can use the real URL instead.

Comment: thenk you for answer. i use url for open my site like http://root:root@localhost/ but console.log(window.location.href); showed information like "http://localhost/" without login: root  password: root

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code that you have tried and a screenshot of the problem? I think that's the last step you need before we can solve this problem.

Comment: You can see img by this link https://ibb.co/HFwJMtr

Comment: window.location.href does not contain this data. How can i get root root from url? Thank you for your patience

Comment: @pashamih please edit your question with your current code and a screenshot. Please run the code in your browser console and show what window.location.href is. Thanks!